# How to use @STRING variables in the note field of a .bib file?

Tags: bibtex, strings

I defined a `@STRING` in my **.bib** file as follows:

```
@STRING{mytext = {Last accessed: }}
```

This is an entry in the bibliography.

```
@ARTICLE{knuth:1974,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {{C}omputer {P}rogramming as an {A}rt},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  year = {1974},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {667--673},
  number = {12},
  month = {December },
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  publisher = {ACM Press},
  note = {Last accessed: 09/20/12}
}
```

I want to use `mytext` as a template so I can easily change it. The `note` field however contains more then the template text.
How can I use the `mytext` variable in the `note` field?

Comment: have you tried `note = mytext`?

Comment: No. Because of the braces the variable name is interpreted as text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
@string{mytext = "This is the text"}
```

and then in the `.bib` entry:

```
@ARTICLE{knuth:1974,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {{C}omputer {P}rogramming as an {A}rt},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  year = {1974},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {667--673},
  number = {12},
  month = {December },
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  publisher = {ACM Press},
  note = mytext
}
```

However, this won't work if the `note` field contains more than just the `@string` text.  Instead you could use `@preamble` (if you want to keep such commands in your `.bib` file):

```
@preamble{ "\newcommand{\mytext}{Last accessed:}" }

@ARTICLE{knuth:1974,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {{C}omputer {P}rogramming as an {A}rt},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  year = {1974},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {667--673},
  number = {12},
  month = {December },
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  publisher = {ACM Press},
  note = {\mytext{} 09/20/12}
}
```

For further details, one can always turn to 'Tame the BeaST' by Nicholas Markey: `texdoc ttb`.

Answer (score 17):

You can concatenate strings in a bib file with the number sign, #, but only if the strings were surrounded with double-quotes (instead of curly braces).

```
@STRING{mytext = "Last accessed: "}

@ARTICLE{ key,
  ...
  note = mytext # "09/20/12"
}
```

See: http://www.bibtex.org/Format/