# How to nest strings inside hyperlinks

Tags: bibtex

I want a bibliography item to generate a hyperlink in which the clickable text is composed by a string defined with `@string{foo = "foo"}` and a not-predefined string concatenated to it by `#`.

In short, I want the entry

```
note = {Also found in } # foo # {bar}
```

to generate something like `Also found in \href{<address>}{foobar}`.

I know that the style `apsrev4-1` does something similar with the `doi` entry, composing a series of strings containing journal data into a single hyperlink. Is there any way to do this at the `.bib` file level?

Comment: I don't think you can concatenate strings defined by `@string` within an entry field.  You can define arbitrary commands with `@preamble{ "\newcommand\stuff[2]{Also found in \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#2}}" }` and then use them in an entry field like `note = {\stuff{10.10...}{text goes here}}`.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly is a step towards what I want. Now is there a way to define this command so that it accepts  a predefined `@string` as one of the arguments?

Comment: No, as I said, I think it is impossible to have a "string" mixed with "non-string" stuff in the same field.  YOu can't have `@string{xxx = "This is a string"}` and then have in (say) something like `note = {Note this string: xxx},` and expect `xxx` to 'expand' to something else. That's why I suggest defining macros, which will expand --- you can even put a `\cite` command in the `note` field and that will work, though it would require doing `latex, bibtex, latex, bibtex, latex, latex` for the embedded citation to appear.

Comment: Is there then no way to have a string passed on as the argument of a command and expanded therein?

Comment: Do you mean like the way the `etoolbox` package provides `\csdef{xxx}{This is what 'xxx' expands to}` which can then be accessed by `\csuse{xxx}`?

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected in part: I guess I never learned about BibTeX' ability to concatenate strings, as seen [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118898/8528).  (Ironically in an answer posted 'below' one of my own!!)  However, I guess this isn't good enough for what you are hoping for....

Comment: Yes, in a way. Another way to put it is: once I define the variable `xxx` by `@string{xxx = 'content'}` can I access the content of that variable in a way other than just concatenating with `#`, for example from within a LaTeX command?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11186/discussion-between-sir-whiteout-and-jon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As discussed in chat.) 
The issue is how to be able to be able to use defined strings in the bibliography, such as

```
@string{grg = "Gen.\ Relativ.\ Gravi.\@"}
```

but also use a string as part of a regular field.  One solution is to make use of an `@preamble` definition and then set the `@string` to that:

```
@preamble{ "\newcommand{\grg}{Gen. Relativ. Gravit.}" }
@string{grg = "\grg"}
```

Then, if you are so inclined, you could do something like:

```
@article{test,
  ...
  journal = grg,
  ...
  note = {Reprinted in \href{link-to-doi}{\grg{} xx(yy),zzzz}
}
```

A full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{ "\newcommand{\grg}{Gen.\ Rel.\ Grav.}" }
@string{grg = "\grg"}

@article{bb,
  author = {Smith, John},
  title =  {Article Title},
  journal = grg,
  year =    2000,
  note =    {Reprinted in \href{DOI-link}{\grg{} xx(yy), zzzz}},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{bb}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```